# Link static library when building a shared library in gcc

Tags: gcc, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I am trying to build a shared library for a jni call. I created a static library using -shared switch when building. I need to now build a shared library which depends on this static library. I tried using -l when building the shared library. Build fails saying that the headers I included from the static libraries are not available. What exactly am i supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

Add `-I/path/to/static/library/headers` to `CFLAGS`,  `-L/path/to/static/library` to `LDFLAGS` and it will no longer complain.

Comment: The codebase I created the static library from doesn't have headers seperated into an include folder. It has a SRC folder which contains all the source files and headers. I created the static library gcc -shared command like I had posted earlier. Does gcc preserve folder structure? I used -I/path/to/static/library/SRC in place of CFLAGS but that doesn;t seem to be working

Comment: Well @KavithaMadhu you should add them to your existing `CFLAGS` not using them as your only `CFLAGS`. Also, having mixed source/header files are okay. And, GCC does not touch your folder structure. And, when you compile the things, you should use `gcc -c -fPIC` on every file to generate object files then link them together using `gcc -shared` to form a final shared library.